# Form validation ?

Tags: forms, validation

I'm new to Javascript and attempting form validation.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here any tips ?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
      <TITLE>Comment Form</TITLE>

      <script type ="text/javascript"> 
          function Validate() {
          }

          Message = ""
          Message = Message + CheckName()
          Message = Message + CheckEmail()
          Message = Message + CheckComments()


         if (Message =="") {
             return true
         }
         else {
            alert(Message)
            return false
         }

    }

    funtion CheckName()
        UserName = document.f1.Name.value

        if(UserName =="") {
             Message ="Please enter your name"
        }
else 
Message=""
}
return Message 

}
```

//Checking E-mail:

```
function CheckEmail() {
email = document.f1.Email.value
AtPos = email.indexOf("@")
StopPos = email.lastIndexOf(".")
Message = ""

if (email == "") {
Message = "Not a valid Email address" + "\n"
}

//if blank: 

if (AtPos == -1 || StopPos == -1) {
Message = "Not a valid email address"
}

//if no @ and no . 


if (StopPos < AtPos) {
Message = "Not a valid email address"
}

//if . before @ 

if (StopPos - AtPos == 1) {
Message = "Not a valid email address"
} 

return Message
}
```

Is there perhaps something missing from the section below the end script ?
Do I need to put something "" in the action field ?   It is asking me to put more text only what am I meant to put here just to fill in space ? Are there alternative ways to achieving what i'm trying to do here ? Is this a dated method ?

```
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR = White>
<form name="f1" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return Validate()" enctype = text/plain>
  <table width="672" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr> 
      <td width="142" valign="top" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="top" height="45" colspan="4" align="center"> <b>Name:</b> 
        <input type="text" name="Name" size="30">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td height="40" valign="top" colspan="4" align="center"><b>Email: 
        <input type="text" name="Email" size="30">
                <td height="151" valign="top" colspan="4" align="center"> 
        <textarea name="Comments" cols="40" rows="7">Add Your Comments here</textarea>
      </td>

    </tr>
       </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: you have written the code outside the function **Validate** which is empty right now.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you immediately close your validate function

```
function Validate() {
}
```

So calling

```
OnSubmit=Validate()
```

will do absolutely nothing.

Start with removing the closing } and make sure that your Validate function actually contains the validation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following link

[Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

and surly you can get your answer with description which thing is use for what ?